# Using canvas.clipRect() with Roboelectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am trying to understand the behavior of canvas.clipRect() when running tests with Roboelectric. With the code snippet below, clipRect returns false when I would expect it to return true under a normal device/emulator test.

```
@Test
// 'robolectric', version: '3.1.1'
// sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
public void testCanvasClip(){
 Canvas c = new Canvas();
 c.setBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
 assertTrue(c.clipRect(0, 0, 25, 25, Region.Op.REPLACE)); // this fails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Canvas` is not implemented in Robolectric, it does nothing as far as I can tell.

I ended up mocking the canvas, even though it's bad practice to mock android classes.